# Python if logic data not able to capture

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Trying to capture the output stats, code below where I check for the Boolean condition. if true add to the body else pass or don't add any detail to the contain. Below logic work if final condition is true else nothing is captured within the contain. please advise how to achieve the contain based on different Boolean condition

```
fail = True
success = True
count = False

contain = ''
contain = contain + "\nFailed\n" if fail else ''
contain = contain + "\nSuccess\n" if success else ''
contain = contain + "\nCount\n" if count else ''

print(contain)
```

expected output

```
Failed

Success
```

current output is blank

However, if I change count variable to true, I'm able to achieve the expected output. But variable value are not always true. Need to capture only true condition

Comment: Use parentheses. The code is interpreting it as `(contain + "\nCount\n") if fail else ''` instead of `contain + ("\nCount\n" if fail else '')`

Comment: thank youm that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
fail = True
success = True
count = False

contain = ''
contain+= "\nFailed\n" if fail else ''
contain+= "\nSuccess\n" if success else ''
contain+= "\nCount\n" if count else ''

print(contain)
```

In the above code these three lines will concatenate the result of the ternary operation to contain.

```
contain+= "\nFailed\n" if fail else ''
contain+= "\nSuccess\n" if success else ''
contain+= "\nCount\n" if count else ''
```

In the original code the equivalent lines would set the value of contain to the result of the ternary operation.

So on the last line where count is False, contain is set to ''.

Probably not the best explanation, perhaps interspersing the code with some print statements might clarify.

```
fail = True
success = True
count = False

contain = ''

contain = contain + "\nFailed\n" if fail else ''
print(f'contain: {contain}')
contain = contain + "\nSuccess\n" if success else ''
print(f'contain: {contain}')
contain = contain + "\nCount\n" if count else ''
print(f'contain: {contain}')
```

Comment: Good code. If you add some explanation this may be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your current if block translates to the following:

```
if fail:
    temp = contain +  "\nFailed\n"
    contain = temp
else:
    contain = ''

if success:
    temp = contain +  "\nSuccess\n"
    contain = temp
else:
    contain = ''

if count:
    temp = contain +  "\nCount\n"
    contain = temp
else:
    contain = ''
```

Now, because the count is False, hence contain is assigned an empty string. Before this if block, contain will be having correct values. You can verify this by adding print statement after your conditionals.

You can try the below code for correct answers:

```
contain = ''
contain += "\nFailed\n" if fail else ''
contain += "\nSuccess\n" if success else ''
contain += "\nCount\n" if count else ''
```

In this case, you are only deciding what to append to the existing string.